# Controlling proxy for WMS using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms, proxy

I operate behind a firewall at work, and so to access the plugins and other external features for QGIS I need to use a proxy.
We also have our own WMS server - which doesn't like the proxy.
To access the internal WMS, I need the proxy off, to access an external WFS I need it on.

Is there a way to control the proxy (as found in Settings > Options > Network)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Options -> Network, you can type addresses in "Exclude URLs" to bypass the proxy.